# Change publisher name when deploying application

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, installation

How do I change the `Publisher` field form `Unknown` to something else.

(I'm using Visual Studio and using `Setup Project` as my installer)

Example below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to digitally sign the package with a [code signing certificate](https://www.thawte.com/code-signing/content-signing-certificates/microsoft-authenticode/index.html) acquired from a certified vendor (Thawtee, VeriSign, etc...). You cannot use a self-generated certificate.

Windows OS automatically uses the company name you specified when building the setup package, **but only** if the package is digitally signed.